# Is there any .NET Core analogue to the stream.on('data') used with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, .net, node.js, stream, .net-core

Stream are very common inside Node.js and they are really easy to deal with. It is very simple to create one stream, and once we have one, we can do something like:

```
stream.on('data', (data) => {
    // processing
});
```

to process the data as it comes from the stream.

Is there any .NET Core analogue to this? I mean, I *do know* that .NET is very different, since there is no Event Loop and so forth.

But I'm wondering if, despite being fundamentally different than Node.js, we could accomplish the same kind of behavior.

Comment: Look into RX. It's the closest thing to the pattern you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest difference is in the async model: C# uses `async`-`await` for asynchrony, not callbacks. Then there is difference in the API: you can either use `Stream`, which gives you data as a `byte[]` (which you have to allocate yourself). Or you can use `StreamReader`, which gives you data as `char[]` or lines as `string`.

So, your options are:

`Stream.ReadAsync`:

```
Stream stream = …;
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int read;
while ((read = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) != 0)
{
    // processing
}
```

`StreamReader.ReadAsync`:

```
StreamReader stream = …;
char[] buffer = new char[1024];
int read;
while ((read = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) != 0)
{    
    // processing
}
```

`StreamReader.ReadLineAsync`:

```
StreamReader stream = …;
string line;

while ((line = await stream.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
{
    // processing
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Potentially.

Look at the MSDN documentation for System.IO.Stream.

There are different types of streams.